# sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```py
clean_df = clean_df.groupby(by=index_keys).sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

throws

```
sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I understand from related questions that this has to do with updating packages. How to find out which package is having the problem?

```sh
$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.0
```

```sh
>python -m pip check
No broken requirements found.
```

Comment: What happens if you `python -m pip check` in the terminal?

Comment: why do you need axis=1? it sums up by column axis anyway when u do groupby sum.

Comment: look at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html , it has no axis keyword.

Comment: Following the comment by @ABC, it is worth noting that `groupby` returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` and not a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I don't think `groupby().sum()` has an axis argument. What are you trying to do with `axis=1`? sum along the rows? then why groupby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed in comments the method `groupby` returns the object [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html). The method [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) that you can use with `GroupBy` doesn't have the parameter `axis`:

> GroupBy.sum(numeric_only=True, min_count=0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
df=df.groupby('columnname').sum(numeric_only=True, min_count=0)
print(df.sum(axis=1))

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.